# Angular routing gives incorrect component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an issue with angular routing.
When I try to go to the `my.domain/new-york` I've got correct page (`HomeComponent`)
But when I try to go to the `my.domain/new-york/search` I've got `HomeComponent` to instead `SearchComponent`. What I did wrong?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BasicComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          headerDark: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: ':city',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          headerDark: true
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: ':category',
            component: HomeComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'search',
            component: SearchComponent,
            data: {
              headerDark: true
            }
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

UPD:
I use two modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/basic/basic.module').then(mod => mod.BasicModule),
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(mod => mod.DashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
  }
];
```

UPD 2: Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghafx6?file=src%2Fapp%2Forders%2Forders-routing.module.ts

Comment: You have a path overload here. What you see is a HomeComponent with the category 'search'.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i see always HomeComponent, even i change {
            path: ':category',
            component: HomeComponent
          }, to SearchComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of routes are very important if you are using dynamic routes.

Here issue is issue is `search` after city name is consider as `category` because `category` is a `dynamic route` and it comes before `static route`. So it is always recommended that `dynamic route` must comes at the end.

For your problem change you routes this way will solve your problem.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BasicComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          headerDark: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: ':city',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: {
          headerDark: true
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'search',
            component: SearchComponent,
            data: {
              headerDark: true
            }
          },
          {
            path: ':category',
            component: HomeComponent
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

See the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvlw7m) for reference

**EDITED**

As per your stackblitz below 2 changes required.

1. **city.component.html**

   added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
2. **orders.component.html**

```html
    <a [routerLink]="['/new-york']">
      City
    </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/new-york/shops']">
      Category
    </a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/new-york/search']">
      Search
    </a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

See the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghafx6-bwecbx) for reference

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, that solution didn't work for me, maybe the reason is using modules? sorry for missing information

Comment: That's not the issue it will work with module too. Can you please create stackblitz so i can help you more.

Comment: @IgorZinchenko see this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvlw7m I have used basic module in this.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghafx6?file=src%2Fapp%2Forders%2Forders-routing.module.ts

Comment: 2 things you are missing. 1. Every parent component's html must contain `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your example `OrdersComponent` and `CityComponent` are parent but you have added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` only in `OrdersComponent`. 2. In `routerLink` routes should start with '/' and '/new-york/shop/search' is replaced with '/new-york/search'. See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghafx6-bwecbx

Comment: omg you are right! i should do something like that {
        path: ':city/:category',
        component: SearchComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':city/search',
        component: SearchComponent,
        data: {
          headerDark: true
        }
      } thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This is because in your code, you have initialized the `/:category` first before the `search` so the `search` keyword was being read as a category parameter.

Try to reorder the routes to:

```
children: [
  {
     path: 'search',
     component: SearchComponent,
     data: {
       headerDark: true
     }
  },
  {
     path: ':category',
     component: HomeComponent
  },
]
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also try multiple parameter instances using this method.
Take note of the order.

**Method #1:**

Attached [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-multiple-routes?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts) for your reference. You can check it's console as well

```
children: [
  {
    path: ':city/search',
    component: SearchComponent
  },
  { 
    path: ':city/:category',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  { 
    path: ':city',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
]
```

**Method #2:**

Based on your routes above and upon testing what you wanted to do on those routes under the `:city` is that you wanted to render those components under the CityComponent or in your case at HomeComponent but no children is being rendered?

This is because you need to add a `<router-outlet>` inside your HomeComponent to render your children components.

```
{
   path: ':city',                           // This is your parent route and parent component which you expect those child components below will be rendered in here. Thus, you need to specify a router-outlet in here.
   component: HomeComponent,
   ...
   children: [                              // This is your child components that will render/reflect it's templates to their parent above or in this case, inside the HomeComponent 
      {
        path: ':category',
        component: HomeComponent            // This will render the category -> home template/component inside the parent's HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent,         // this will render the search template/component inside the parent's HomeComponent
      }
    ]
},
```

If you want to have it in distinct routes, the Method #1 solution above would help you with it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, thats work for mydomain.com/search, but how fix it for mydomain.com/city/search

Comment: If you follow @KShewengger instructions it will work in that case also.

Comment: @StPaulis https://codepen.io/ihorvimmi/pen/poyEBRg sorry, here is my config, what i did wrong? i dont see((

Comment: @IgorZinchenko In your codepen you have by mistake linked SearchComponent with ':category'.

Comment: @VivekJain it's doesn't matter, SearchComponent didn't display at all

Comment: Hi @IgorZinchenko, i have updated my answer with 2 methods. Hope it helps

Comment: @KShewengger, unfortunately, no, I add example there https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghafx6?file=src%2Fapp%2Forders%2Forders-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @KShewengger didn't work for me because I didn't want the ChildComponents (SearchComponent) to be rendered inside the ParentComponent (HomeComponent). In my case I was only using the routing config to construct a breadcrumb. My ChildComponents however should always be rendered in my global `<router-outlet>` in my `AppComponent` completely replacing the ParentComponent in the DOM

My solution ended up like this:

```
{
   path: ':city',
   children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent,
      }
      {
        path: ':category',
        component: HomeComponent
      }
    ]
},
```

A bit of explanation (although I'm no 100% sure about that): If you have childroutes, you always need a `<router-outlet>` in the ParentComponent. Else the child routes are pretty much ignored.

Changing the `path: ':city'` to be a componentless route was crucial here, so that my SearchComponent got rendered in the end.

I'm still quite the Angular noob and can't explain all the internals, but I hope this might help someone in the future.